"L'amoureux"— can be plural?
In the province where I live, we have a Member of Parliament whose family name is "Lamoureux". This seems pretty clearly to be the word "l'amoureux", which to me means literally "the one who loves" ("the amorous one"), but which I understand to be used to mean "the lover".
I recently had someone for whom French is their first language tell me that "l'amoureux" could mean either "the lover" or "the lovers", plural. When I asked them to explain to me, they simply said, "Interpret it however you want, I'm not a teacher." :-P
Can "l'amoureux" be plural? Or does the use of l' (which cannot be a contracted form of les, I think?) imply specifically singular?

Lamoureux is a proper noun. Family names are written identically in singular and in plural in French so you can say un Lamoureux to mean one member of that family and les Lamoureux to name them all.
When amoureux is a masculine substantive or an adjective, it is invariable so it is un amoureux, l'amoureux, des amoureux, les amoureux, etc.
You are right l'amoureux can't be a plural but maybe that native French person was only thinking of the fact amoureux is invariable and overlook you were focusing on the article.
The feminine form isn't invariable: une amoureuse, des amoureuses.

Thanks very much :-)

Etymology: Any idea why "un amoureux" has an x in the singular? Are there other words like this?

@Eggy Many adjectives/nouns share that suffix, e.g. : affreux, frileux, heureux, miséreux, paresseux, peureux, vaniteux; ambitieux, anxieux, audacieux, curieux, facétieux, furieux, malicieux, orgueilleux, prétentieux, séditieux, vicieux; présomptueux.  That suffix indicates a "fullness": amoureux = "full of love".

Thank you! Very interesting.
